# What should I write inside form action to navigate to next wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to navigate to another wordpress page (super3), when I submitting the value of the input filed, but It gives me a error that the server can not find the url.
Can somebody give me a hint on how to solve the problem...

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/super3/" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="next!">
</form>
```

Comment: do you know what `bloginfo('template_url')` returns? assuming you want your site address, use `site_url()`

Comment: Or `bloginfo('url');`

Comment: @kennypu Sory, but site_url() is not working...

Comment: @KristerAndersson Sory, but bloginfo('url') is not working...

Comment: What version of wordpress are you using and what does `site_url()` and `bloginfo('url')` returns?

Comment: @KristerAndersson This is the error i get:  Not Found

A 404 error, page not found, is an code that means that the page you were trying to reach on a website couldnt be found on their server. Wordpress version 3.9.1

Comment: I know what 404 means, the question was what does `site_url()` and `bloginfo('url')` returns? Also, are you able to access the url by typing it directly in your browser i.e: `example.com/super3/`? If not, then you haven't configured the permalinks correctly.

Comment: have you tried to remove the last slash? Also, the permalinks are configured with %postname% ?

Comment: if the url isn't working, your permalink is probably not setup, or the .htaccess is not setup